# z-index woes: svg element appearing behind canvas elements when it shouldn't be

Tags: css, html, svg, html5-canvas, z-order

I've been trying to make a HTML5 version of the cover of The Dark Knight Returns (the one with the lightning) for the last couple of hours.

I've pretty much finished but the svg batman I've made refuses to go in front of the canvases!

the page with the problem is up at: http://scaryg.nom.es/playthings/lightningbadsvg

I've looked and the svg element appears to be locating the right css rules, and I've tried resetting the canvases to their correct z-index during the initialisation process (as well as being set to the correct z-index in the style sheet).

Everything's on the one page (even the svg) and I'm stumped.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your style being applied to `svg`:

```
position:absolute: top:30%;
```

Notice the colon instead of semicolon after `absolute`. Fix that and the batman will be infront.

Try using a tool such as Developer tools or Firebug to detect these types of issues.